# merge two datasource to gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

what is the best way of doing?, i have one table that returns one set of data and another table that returns another set of data, so in my gridview i want to display

id,name = dataset1
registration_id, registration_name = dataset2

### gridview looks like this:

### id | name | reg_id | reg_name |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best bet is to use a [JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx) when selecting the data from the database.

If that's not possible, there are several ways to accomplish this with DataTable objects in memory...

One possibility is outlined here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/shahed/archive/2009/02/09/asp-net-tips-display-resultset-from-multiple-datatable.aspx  This is how I usually do it if I absolutely can't just get it directly from the server in the format I want.

You can also do it using [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397908.aspx)

An example of a JOIN with LINQ can also be found here: http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/ShahanDev/4601/Default.aspx

**Edit - added based on comments**

Based on your comments, I'm not sure that joining the results in a gridview is necessarily what you want.  In a one-to-many relationship you will get duplicaiton from the "one" side.

If I'm guessing right, what you really want is something that more accurately represents the one-to-many relationship so instead of data that looks like this:

```
id | name | reg_id | reg_name |
1  |abs   | 1      |adad      |
1  |abs   | 2      |sadsd     |
```

you really want it to look like this:

```
1  abs
   1   adad
   2   sadsd
```

In that case, you're better off looking into Nested Repeaters: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154  or another way to represent heriarchical data.

Comment: i did try with join but the problem i am having with join is:  my table has one to many relationship: for an example: i have `Id = 100` and `reg_id` i have `343,234,423` so after i execute the sql i get 3 rows. make sense?

Comment: i agree that i am looking for the master/detail approach but one thing that makes me confuse that, in my situation both (master/detail) should be editable to the user to udpate the row... so should i still use master/detail approach for the above situation?

Comment: I would use this pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx You could also save yourself tons of time by using Microsoft Dynamic Data, which handles simple CRUD operations very nicely. http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata

Comment: will that be able to edit inline? before i go that path i just wanted to make sure.....in my detailView i will have reg_name and this (reg_name) will be dynamic can have one or 10 and i am generating based on how many counts i have from tbl and then creating textbox based on that...... so when the user clicks on EDIT it should edit both MASTER/EDIT row.... the microsoft pattern will help? - for dynamic data, i am not sure i havent worked on that before.

Comment: Yes, it will work for editing - both the master and the detail. As for Dynamic Data, it took me one time watching a video and going through the same steps with my own database to learn how to do it.  I'd strongly recommend at least watching this video: http://www.asp.net/aspnet-in-net-35-sp1/videos/getting-started-with-dynamic-data and then checking out the other videos here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data

Answer (score 0):

I think in addition to all the great previos methods , you can write a stored procedure,which contains your logic (you can use temporary tables #table),make it the grid view data source..i use stored procedures many times when i need data from many tables to avoid complex joins and nested controls which may cause low performance according to what i know.

if u mean u use two data sources for the same grid view but the source changes according to some condition , this will help u ..

[gridview with more than one data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314137/gridview-with-more-than-one-data-source)